# ¿Cómo embeber un script de gits github en un blog de Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo el siguiente script en gits github :

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/gilbertoquinteroA/93d3216201c1a3d8c5a46fb9a56a129a.js"></script>
```

Y me gustaría saber si es posible o si es posible embeberlo en un post de wordpress.com.

Comment: Al parecer buscas [esto](https://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/).

Answer (score 1):

**EDICION**:

Para poner un script de gits en tu blog de wordpress, tienes que pegar el enlace en su propia línea de texto entre unos `<p> </p>` y aparecerá solo incrustado

Quedaría así en tu código HTML:

```
<p><script src="https://gist.github.com/93d3216201c1a3d8c5a46fb9a56a129a.js"></script></p>
```